# problem installing phpmyadmin on windows 10

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I Got the same problem installing phpmyadmin on windows 10 some one posted and was treated as duplicate,right click the link 1.32.249.15/phpmyadmin

Comment: right click the link http://1.32.249.15/phpmyadmin

Comment: The link you posted here is very insecure

Comment: http:// then continue